# Consulta DNS para encontrar el CNAME

Tags: dns, cli

Como puedo encontrar el registro de tipo CNAME de **www.google.es** usando el comando **dig**,  **host** y **nslookup**

Answer (score 2):

Con **nslookup** puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

1. nslookup

Una vez te aparece el prompt >

2. set type=CNAME
3. www.google.es

Saludos.
David.

Answer (score 0):

Con dig puedes hacerlo así:

dig CNAME www.google.es

Esta opción realizará el query al servidor DNS configurado en el equipo desde el cual se ejecute el comando (localhost ó 127.0.0.1)

Sin embargo, para hacer el query a un servidor específico puedes hacerlo asi:

dig CNAME @1.1.1.1 www.google.es